# Using flexbox for figures' figcaption

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The main goal is to make figcaptions' content maximum adaptive as we don't know the exact size of its content. Title of figure is always shown, when we hover the figcaption shows up with its whole sized content. Why flexbox? Unhovered figure squeezes text description to 0. When hover flexbox is to grow? I know it is possible, but I miss something to make it. Any ideas of my mistake?

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif; 
}
.wrapper {
 text-align: center;
}
img{
 vertical-align: middle;
}
figure {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 50px auto;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 position: relative;
}
figcaption {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: flex-end; 
 align-content: flex-end;
 text-align: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
}
.news-title {
 border: 1px solid green;
 transition: 300ms;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 10px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    margin: 0;
}
span {
 flex: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid red;
 transition: 300ms;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
figure:hover span {
 flex: 1;
 transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <figure>
  <img src="http://nikolad0.bget.ru/img/news-preview.png" alt="" />
  <figcaption>
   <div class="news-title">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
   </div>
   <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora minima natus repellat optio! Dignissimos, cum quaerat distinctio quibusdam numquam accusantium ipsam laudantium excepturi impedit, laborum cupiditate, nihil reiciendis? Minima, error!</span>
  </figcaption>
 </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly you want do you want it scroll from bottom to up?

Comment: yes, with maximum height of content. Not more, not less. Like here: http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/JXWpKb . But now it 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
              * {
box-sizing: border-box;
 }
body {
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;   
 }
.wrapper {
text-align: center;
 }
 img{
vertical-align: middle;
 }
figure {
display: inline-block;
margin: 50px auto;
border: 1px solid #333;
position: relative;
   }
 figcaption {
display: block;  
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
    width: 100%;
color: #fff;
   }
 .news-title {
border: 1px solid green;
/*transition: 300ms;*/
  }
  h3 {
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
padding: 10px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
margin: 0;
  }
  span {
    display: none;
     width:100%;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid red;
/*transition: 300ms;*/
background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  }
  /*figure:hover span {

transition: 500ms;
  }*/
          </style>




    <div class="wrapper">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://nikolad0.bget.ru/img/news-preview.png" alt="" />
            <figcaption>
                <div class="news-title">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                </div>
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora minima natus repellat optio! Dignissimos, cum quaerat distinctio quibusdam numquam accusantium ipsam laudantium excepturi impedit, laborum cupiditate, nihil reiciendis? Minima, error!</span>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>


   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
         <script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $("figure").hover(function () {
                     $("span").slideToggle();

                 })

             });
         </script>
```

Comment: Dont think I want to use jq for this )

Comment: without jquery it does not give a slide effect does you want that so i give that code to ??

Comment: The point was to use flexbox abilities, without using max-height hack, b'cuz it has its own issues, like freez before calculating height and transition timings ...